# Rotate through DIVs via Prev & Next Buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a function that will cycle through 3 blocks of DIV's by hitting a "Next" button that will rotate between panel's 1, 2, and 3 consecutively. Hitting the "Prev" button will go back to the previous panel of DIVs.

Really, I just want to cycle through  a few panel of DIVS - hide & showing each of them with the same effect as the jsFiddle.

I know a lot dirty way to make a function to cycle through, but I know there's an easier way versus adding classes, individual functions for each step and button.

Here's my jsFiddle. Click the next button and you'll see how I'm looking to have the "panels" cycled.

http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/

Comment: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/4/

Edited your fiddle so the next button works. If you want me to do the previous button too then let me know. It just sees what panel is visible, hides it and then shows the next panel in the code.

Edit: Added the prev button function too.

Comment: Perfect! How would I "disable" the prev button if the 1st panel is shown? Also, how would I prevent the next button on the 3rd panel stage not to hide it? I.e. when the 3rd panel is shown, the Next  button shouldn't go next. I will have this button change to a form submit.

Comment: Sorted, now you can 1up my answer :) and copy all the code, because I made changes to the html and css to keep the JS as clean as possible.

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks so much for your help! This has helped tremendously!

Comment: One question though - the delay on the slideDown is not working. Any idea?

Comment: I'll fix it... paste the code back into the fiddle because it's reset to what you originally pasted, and then I'll edit it.

Comment: Your code is very much like mine. But with added tidyness, readablity, and more use of jQuery functions. I did neary the same with own logic ;)  +1

Comment: just checked the same code I originally wrote and the delay works fine... you may just want to increase it.

Comment: @Jashwant ha yea my OCD means I have to write code that is clear and concise. It's so bad, you should see what I go through keeping my coding structure neat.

Comment: @CoreyRS Question - I want the panels to slide horizontally. I've added code to the PREV & NEXT functions and the first panel slides, but the next group doesn't come in. would you mind taking a look? http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/32/

Comment: strange... i'll see what i can do

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/1/

The NEXT button keeps track of what panel it's on (and sets the initial one) allowing for unlimited panel changes.  It should be fairly simple to do the same for PREV (you will have to keep track of the current panel in a single spot, of course).

Comment: Awesome. How do I prevent the "Next" button when the 3rd panel is loaded to not hide the 3 panel. I.e. when the 3rd panel is shown, the next shouldn't hide it. This would be the last step and will likely be a "Launch" button. (I'm creating a wizard step form).

Also, how about the prev button function? Same deal. If panel 1, prev button shouldn't go anywhere, etc.

Comment: @MikeBarwick oops that sould be `.left-panel' + np).length` to check whether it should be hidden.  For `prev` you will do the same thing, just subtract 1 from `cp` to get `pp`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If use similar structure in my sliders,

**JS**

```
var active = 0;
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $box = $('#area-wrap').find('.box'); 
    $box.eq(active).slideUp(function() {
        if ($btn.hasClass('next')) {
            if (active == $box.length - 1) {
                active = 0;
            }
            else {
                active ++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (active == 0) {
                active = $box.length - 1;
            }
            else {
                active --;
            }
        } 
        $box.eq(active).delay(500).slideDown();
    });

});​
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="area-wrap">

    <!-- First Panel (Start) -->
    <div class='box'>
    <div class="left-panel1">1st Panels</div>
    <div class="right-panel1">1st Panels</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Panel (Hidden) -->
    <div class='box hidden'>
        <div class="left-panel2">2nd Panels</div>
        <div class="right-panel2">2nd Panels</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Panel (Hidden) -->
    <div class='box hidden'>
    <div class="left-panel3" >3rd Panels</div>
    <div class="right-panel3">3rd Panels</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div class="btn next">NEXT</div>
    <div class="btn prev">PREV</div>

</div>​
```

and added

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

to CSS.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zpSrj/4/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/1/

Took @Explosion Pills and made it so when you are on the 3rd it goes back to the 1st when you hit next.